# How can I save an Email to a Google Sites page using AppsScript

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sites

I often have something on my mobile phone that I'd like to keep for future reference. Maybe a photo or an interesting link to an article to read later on a computer.

How can I save this information via email on my phone so that the email content is stored in a Google Sites page using Google AppsScript

Answer (score 0):

This apps script code works. Have it trigger on a timer (say every 5mins) and any emails sent to your gmail account with **emailarch** in the subject will be added to the page as child pages with attachments. The parent page list will be updated.

The Sites page should be of type List with two text columns Date and Item.

```
/**
 */
function createEmailArch() {
  var site          = 'YOURSITE';
  var page_name     = 'APAGEINYOURSITE';
  var site_url      = 'https://sites.google.com/site/'+site+'/'+page_name;

  var site          = SitesApp.getSite(site);
  var page          = site.getChildByName(page_name);
  var curr_date     = new Date();
  var curr_date_fmt = Utilities.formatDate(curr_date,'Australia/Melbourne','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  var threads       = GmailApp.search('subject:"emailarch" is:unread');

  for ( var j = 0 ; j<threads.length;j++) {
    var messages = threads[j].getMessages();
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++ ) {
      var message  =  messages[i];

      var subj = message.getSubject();
      var body = message.getBody();
      var mdte = message.getDate();
      var mfrm = message.getFrom();
      var meto = message.getTo();
      var atta = message.getAttachments();

      var cont = "Subject : "+subj+"<br/>"+
               "To : "+meto+"<br/>"+
               "From : "+mfrm+"<br/>"+
               "Date : "+mdte+"<br/>"+
               body;

      var dte2 = Utilities.formatDate(curr_date,"Australia/Melbourne","yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")+"_"+j+"_"+i;
      for ( var k=0;k<atta.length;k++) {
        var iname = atta[k].getName();
        if ( atta[k].getContentType().indexOf('image')>=0 ) { // If attachment is an image show inline
          cont = cont +"<hr/>"+
           "<div style='display:block;text-align:left'>"+
           "<a href='"+site_url+"/"+dte2+"/"+iname+"?attredirects=0' imageanchor='1'>"+
           "<img src='"+site_url+"/"+dte2+"/"+iname+"?height=400&amp;width=224' border='0' height='400' width='224'>"+
           "</a></div><br/>";
        }
      }
      var p = page.createWebPage(curr_date_fmt,dte2,cont);
      for ( var k=0;k<atta.length;k++) {
        p.addHostedAttachment(atta[k]);
      }
      page.addListItem( [curr_date_fmt, "<a href='"+site_url+"/"+dte2+"'>"+subj+"</a>"]);
      message.markRead();
    }
  }

};
```